# In Javascript Engine (for v8), what exactly means "implicit call" in optimization phases?

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm newbie at javascript engine. In optimization phases, if `implicit call` is in some block, optimizer need to add some check for this block. In this context, what `implicit call` exactly means?

As i understand, i think below one is `implicit call(cb function)`.
Is that right?

```
function foo(x, cb){
    let arr = [1,2,3,4];
    cb();
    return arr[1];
}
```

Comment: Q: Where did you encounter this term?

Comment: @JVApen I remove it. sorry !
@paulsm4 Sorry,,, i forgot where i saw that term... but article that i saw describes javascript engine's wrong optimization assumption could lead to serious security issues. In above example code, `cb()` may change `arr` type, but, if redundant checkmap operations are improperly removed, that issues important security problems.

Comment: Can you link that article, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 developer here. I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean, so I'll give it my best guess: an "implicit call" is a call that's not immediately obvious from its syntax.

The call in your example is very explicit: anyone (human or compiler) looking at the code can immediately see that there's a call there. But consider this example:

```
function addFields(a, b) {
  return a.field + b.field;
}
```

No calls, right? But now consider code like this elsewhere in the application:

```
var b = {field: 42};
var a = {get field() {delete b.field; return 0;}}
console.log(addFields(a, b));
```

Suddenly, what looks like a simple field load will *implicitly call* a user-defined function, which could have all sorts of side effects (like modifying an unrelated object).

Other examples of implicit calls are expressions like `"the value is: " + x`, which will implicitly call `x.toString()` if `x` is not a String already.

Comment: Thank you for answer !! That's what i want ! Sorry for my opaque question.

Comment: In that case, you can mark this answer as "Accepted" ;-)